pyspark - explode a dataframe col, which contains json
I have a column 'user_contacts_attributes ' in spark dataframe:
+------------------+-------------------------------------+

|    user_name       |user_contacts_attributes           |

+------------------+-------------------------------------+

|    Test          |  "user": { "id": "16","username":"sam","level":"2.00"}                       |             
+------------------+-------------------------------------+

the dataframe has a schema as below:
user_name:string
 
user_contacts_attributes:struct
user:struct
id:string
level:string
username:string

The resultant dataframe has to be as below:
+------------------++------------------+---------------------------+
|    user_name     |parent             |child   | value        |
+------------------+---------------------------++------------------+
|              Test|user               |  id     | 16              |
|              Test|user               |level    | 2.00|
|              Test|user               |username | sam |
+------------------+---------------------------+-------------------+

I have tried writing UDF similar to this PySpark "explode" dict in column
But failed. I need a udf that I can apply to each of these dataframe rows

Use an SQL expression to create a new column containing an array of named_structs, where each struct contains the field name and field value of one json element:
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = ....

base = 'user_contacts_attributes.user' # according the the schema 'user' is a fixed string
# get all json elements:
fields = df.select(f'{base}.*').schema.fieldNames() 
# create the expression for the array
expr = "array(" + \
  ",".join([f'named_struct("child", "{field}", "value", {base}.{field})' for field in fields]) \
 + ")"
 

expr now contains the string
array(
  named_struct("child", "id", "value", user_contacts_attributes.user.id),
  named_struct("child", "level", "value", user_contacts_attributes.user.level),
  named_struct("child", "username", "value", user_contacts_attributes.user.username)
)

Finally explode the array and remove the intermediate columns:
df.withColumn('parent', F.lit('user'))\
  .withColumn('values', F.expr(expr)) \
  .withColumn('values', F.explode("values")) \
  .withColumn("child", F.col("values.child")) \
  .withColumn("value", F.col("values.value")) \
  .drop("user_contacts_attributes", "values") \
  .show(truncate=False)

Output:
+---------+------+--------+-----+
|user_name|parent|child   |value|
+---------+------+--------+-----+
|Test     |user  |id      |16   |
|Test     |user  |level   |2.00 |
|Test     |user  |username|sam  |
+---------+------+--------+-----+

If possible, using UDFs should be avoided as they are slower than SQL functions.

This works, thank you so much!
